# How to set the value of Autocomplete Input Box while using Jquery Autocomplete with JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, mysql, jsp

Thanks in advance.
I have a Autocomplete Input Field where we can type the string and using jquery Autocomplete I get the dropdown from a JSP page and that JSP page calls the Java function to retreive the data from MYSQL.

the HTML code is as follows.

```
<form>
        <input type="hidden" id="autosuggest" name="autosuggest" value="Y"/>
        <input type="text" name="Category" id="searchp" value="">
        <script>
            $("#searchp").autocomplete({
                delay: 100,
                autoFocus: true,
                selectFirst: true,
                source: 'ProviderSuggest.jsp',
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#autosuggest').val('Y');
                }
            });
        </script>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Below is the code for ProviderSuggest.jsp

```
    <%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@page import="com.google.gson.Gson"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="Functions.DBConnections"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%
    String query = request.getParameter("term");
    List<String> CategoryList = new DBConnections().GetCategoryList(query);
    Iterator CatIterator = CategoryList.iterator();
    String JCategory = "";
    Map CategoryMap = new HashMap();
    while (CatIterator.hasNext()) {
        String Category = (String) CatIterator.next();
        String CategoryID = (String) CatIterator.next();
        CategoryMap.put(CategoryID, Category);
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JCategory = gson.toJson(CategoryMap);
    System.out.println(JCategory);
    //out.print(JCountry);
    out.print(JCategory);
%>
```

Below is the code for the Java Function to get the data from MySql

```
public static List GetCategoryList(String Keyword) {
    List<String> CategoryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL + dbName, dbuserID, dbpwd);
        PreparedStatement preStatement;
        ResultSet resultSet;
        String query = "SELECT Category, CategoryID FROM category WHERE Keywords LIKE '%" + Keyword + "%' AND ParentCatID != 0 Limit 10";
        preStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        resultSet = preStatement.executeQuery(query);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            CategoryList.add(resultSet.getString(1));
            CategoryList.add(resultSet.getString(2));
        }
        resultSet.close();
        preStatement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnections.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return CategoryList;
}
```

If you see the ProviderSuggest.jsp is returning an Array with CategoryID and Category.
When I display them at the front end i am able to display Category and I am trying to set the Value of that Autocomplete Input Field as the CategoryID so that when I submit the form I only send the Category ID for further processing.
May I know what wrong I am doing as I am not able to set the Value of the Input Field to the CategoryID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not JQuery fan/expert, but the line `$('#autosuggest').val('Y');` says set the value to const value `Y`, and it's not the value you got from the server?!

Plus set the `content-type` of response in jsp using

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

And the java code would be more better by having a sql-side function for calling the function(run query), and pass(escape) the value to the function via `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 0):

If you could make the response string like this, you can set key value pairs to text field.

**Check below code:**

```
var availableTags2 = [ {
            label : "Category id1"
            value : "Category val1",
        }, {
             label : "Category id2"
            value : "Category val2",

        } ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. How do I create a json array like you mentioned and how do i set the label and value in jquery

Comment: label and value are hard coded values ,you can append the id and value , i mean you can form the response in jsp,You gave the source as jsp so pl form the string as i meant

Comment: could you plz help me out how do i create this kind of json array using java and how do i access it under jquery autocomplete feature. I am finding it very difficult to get this done. My data is coming from mysql.